# Make custom Python module location detectable in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I am using Pylance extension in Visual Studio Code. It can give me hints about different function names and their attributes etc. based on the modules that I have imported.

It works fine for modules installed with `pip install module`. However, it cannot detect functions which I imported from my own file in a custom location. I import the file like this:

```
import sys, os
file_loc = "D:\\Work\\assets\\includes\\"
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(file_loc))
from funcs import *
```

So, Pylance (or Visual Studio Code) cannot show me any information about functions defined in `funcs`. I also added my folder to the Environment Path variable but that did not help either.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pip` to add your own files to the environment. I would very much recommend doing it in a virtual environment manager like Anaconda. So activate your virtual environment and write this in the terminal.

`pip3 install --editable "D:\\Work\\assets\\includes\\"`

The --editable part lets you change the contents of funcs.py and have it show up immediately in your code (very useful when you are using notebook features).

And I would always recommend that you do

```py
from funcs import function_1, function_2
```

for the sake of your own sanity. It can get confusing in the long run. And be careful with very generic names for your .py files. Put a numbers.py in your folder and it could really mess with your Python ;)

Edit: Oops, meant to add this link to a Reddit post that explains it in more detail than I have here: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/ayx7za/how_does_pip_install_e_work_is_there_a_specific/ei407ao?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3